# Store customer data in two databases

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to store customer data from frontend to the database. Now, there are two databases **Master and Child**. I want to know that how to store that document into child database as well as Master database. I am using MongoDB database, backend Node Express and angular at the frontend. How to tackle this issue, at frontend or backend?

Comment: instead of a master slave architecture, use a mongodb replicaset as they suggest it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/master-slave/

Comment: I think replicaset is for the same database. I forgot to mention it above, I have two different databases with different architecture.

Comment: NEVER expose your database to the frontend. Expose an API from the Express server for the Angular to POST the data. Use the Express server to save the data to your database.

Comment: We are using the API's. but need those api's to work on Two separate databases on two separate servers.

Comment: As I'm thinking, when I submit the data it hits Two api's one for own child database and then the second one the Master Dashboard DB. But I think its not a good approach.

Comment: Secondly use the EDI approach. Now needs the best suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your use case a bit more? What are the "different architectures" of your databases? Are the schemas the same for the documents being written? Are you looking to mirror only a collection or the entire database?

Comment: both schemas are bit different like, schema for child.
{
 cID:   Number,
 fName: String,
 mName: String,
 lName: String,
 email: String,
 ...
}

Schema for Master:
{
 cID:   Number,
 cName: String,
 email: String,
 ...
}

Comment: I want that when I enter the customer data at client end, its data also inserted at master DB. 
lets we have a food-chain store example. when any product is sold out, it deducts the quantity at that store and also deducts the amount at the Warehouse system to notify. same as when the new customer is added at "A" store, Its Parent Store system get updated that this new customer is added in our "A" store.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to effectively duplicate the writes to the *Child* database whenever something changes within the *Master*, this may be a good use case for [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/).

This is something you should be handling on the backend, as you're essentially triggering an action when a change occurs. For a good article on how to do this using NodeJs, see [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@thakkaryash94/mongodb-3-6-change-streams-example-with-node-js-2b9a85652c50).

Comment: change streams are events occuring at every write. OP needs a wholistic solution that writes to specific primary node and reads from a secondary node. Also if you need to extend secondary nodes, change streams would not be a good solution.